# for loop in nodejs not working with redis hexists

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, redis

Executing a for loop with a hexists check in redis, but i am getting response only for the last item in the array. I tried all methods including async and some suggested in stack overflow, but could not get a resolution, not sure what i am missing.

Code is below

```
    reply.forEach(function(replyitem,index){
            parsedReply = JSON.parse(replyitem);

                if(checkMsg(parsedReply.msguuid, index) == null){
                    result.push(parsedReply);
                }
            count++;
        if ((count + 1) == reply.length){
        // Pass the info list to the view
                cd("# of info shown when page is loaded: - " + result.length);
                sendAllLocations(whorequested + ":mylocation", res, result);   
            }
        });



 function checkMsg(msgidVal, index){
                redisClient.hexists(blockedlistname, msgidVal, function (rediserr, exists) {
                if (rediserr) {
                    ce("Error  " + JSON.stringify(rediserr));
                } else if (!exists) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                    cd(" not displaying " + msgidVal);
                }
            }); 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkMsg()` function is making an asynchronous call to the redis database, but then trying to return that value from the `checkMsg()` function.  It will not work that way.  Async values cannot be directly returned from the function.  The function returns BEFORE the async value has even been retrieved.  And, returning the value from within the async callback, just goes back into the database infrastructure, not back to any of your code (e.g. it does nothing useful).

You will have to program with checkMsg in an asynchronous fashion.  It will need a callback or promise that it can return its result in and then all code that uses checkMsg will have to use that callback to examine the result.  You will have to use that function asynchronously like you are doing in other places in your code where you have async operations.